# Should I be using async/await with Task.Run

Tags: .net, asynchronous

In my form's load event I am loading a few things from the database as well as sending out a few updates to the database as well as another service.  With the updates that are going out I have been using Task.Run(() => ) to run these asynchronously.  It seems to me I only want to use the async/await when I want to still do the updates asynchronously while still going sequentially through my form's load event.  In the below example I don't care about setupDBUpdate or sendServiceCall finishing before I hit doOtherWork.

```
void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadData();
    setupDBUpdate();
    sendServiceCall();
    doOtherWork();
}

private void setupDBUpdate()
{
    var timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 60000;
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Task.Run(() =>
  {
    // do database update
  });
}

void sendServiceCall()
{
  Task.Run(() =>
  {
    // connect to service and send an update.
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as long as you have some route to make sure your tasks are done before you try to process the data, everything should be OK.